# How do I pass an event handler as a method parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, methods

How can I pass the event handler **TextBlock_MouseDown_Test1** or **TextBlock_MouseDown_Test2** to SmartGrid so that the TextBlocks which it creates will execute this event handler when they are clicked?

The code below gets the error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'TestDel234.SmartGrid.SmartGrid(TestDel234.Window1,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List,
>   System.EventHandler)' has some invalid
>   arguments

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TestDel234
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> items = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
            SmartGrid sg = new SmartGrid(this, items, TextBlock_MouseDown_Test1);
        }

        private void TextBlock_MouseDown_Test1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("testing1");
        }

        private void TextBlock_MouseDown_Test2(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("testing2");
        }
    }

    public class SmartGrid
    {
        public SmartGrid(Window1 window, List<string> items, EventHandler eventHandler)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                tb.Text = item;
                tb.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(eventHandler);
                window.MainContent.Children.Add(tb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cast your mouse button event args handler to a plain EventHandler - try an `EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs>` in the constructor instead.